# static variable vs stack variable: thread safety vs stack size?

Tags: c++, static, thread-safety

I have a method that needs a lot of memory (compared with stack size) to store temporary results.
I'm considering using static variables as local temporary storage.

I did some research and found out that initialization of static variables is not thread-safe in C++98.

So, question is, what if I just need the space but don't care about the initialization?

Or, further, what is the problem of using static variables as local storage?

Comment: Allocate it on the heap using `std::make_unique`.

Comment: You need a method that needs a lot of memory, explain better the situation.

Comment: Static variables are not allocated on the stack, they are stored in the data section.  Which is not "local temporary storage".  So the entire approach is rather pointless.

Comment: @nbro, this is why I used "compared with stack size". It doesn't need a lot of memory. It's just the stack being small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just a matter of initialization.  A static variable, even one defined within a function, is a single instance that's shared by all calls to that function — even calls in different threads.  If you use a static variable as a scratch buffer, all your threads will be sharing the *same* scratch buffer, and you'll need to use explicit synchronization to keep them from interfering with each other.  You'll also need to figure out how to make the threads share the buffer *effectively*; if they're all trying to use the same parts at the same time and frequently have to wait for mutex locks, you lose the benefit of concurrency and might as well just use a single thread.

It'd be much easier to have the function just allocate its scratch area on the heap and delete it before returning.  (You can use `std::unique_ptr` in C++11 to ensure that the buffer is deleted when the pointer goes out of scope, or `std::auto_ptr` if  you're stuck with C++98.)

Comment: Forgive me that I don't have much knowledge on threads. But aren't non static methods bounded to object scope? Is it possible for different threads to call the same non-static method and access the same copy of static variable in it? Please correct me if anything above seems wrong to you. Thank you.

Comment: Static variables are shared between all threads, even when accessed by code in a non-static method.  The fact that the method is non-static just means that it can *also* access non-static variables stored in the object instance on which it was called.  But a static variable is static no matter how it's accessed.

Comment: Is this also true for the static variable is declared within a non-static method? I feel like I didn't make myself clear from the beginning. By static variables I mean static variables in a method, not static members in a class.

Comment: Yes. Declaring a static variable in a method means that it's visible only within that method, but there's still just one instance of the variable shared between all calls to the method, regardless of which thread performs the call.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. I thought C++ name mangling will let each object to see a different copy of a non-static method, hence a different copy of static variable in it. Thanks for proving me wrong on this.

Comment: Name mangling doesn't create "copies" of a method.  There's only one copy of a method (i.e. its code) regardless of how many instances of the class you create.  When you call a method on several different instances of a class, you're actually calling the same code each time, but passing different values for the `this` pointer that the method uses to find the non-static member variables.  Think of the `this` pointer as a sort of special argument that gets passed automatically based on the object you called the method "on".

Comment: Name mangling is for function overloading:  you can have functions with the same name that take different arguments.  Name mangling encodes the function's argument types into the compiled function's symbol name, so that the linker can find the right function even though there may be several with the same (non-mangled) name.

Answer (score 0):

static variables exist only once. That means if you have multithreaded code where two threads would need the space, you are out of luck. It will bite you one day.

static variables exist forever. That means once you are done with the task needing the space, the space is gone forever. That will bite you from day one.

If you need more memory than you are willing to allocate on the stack (and many implementations have much more severe restrictions for stack memory), then allocate the memory on the heap, and free it when you are done with it.